# Remove duplicates in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, int

There is a problem with this code.  I've added my del method for reference:

```
public void removeAllDuplicates() {
    for (int i = 0; i < counter - 1;) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < counter;) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                del(j);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void del(int place) {
    for (int i = place; i < counter - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    array[counter] = 0;
    counter--;
}
```

Comment: I'm not your down-voter, but you state that `"there is a problem with this code"`, but have not told us what the problem is. Please elaborate; please tell us any and all details that would help us to understand what may be going wrong, so that we can better be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `first for-loop` and `second for-loop` doesn't have incremental conditions on i and j.
The synatax for `for loop` is

`for(initialsiationOfVariables;checkCondition;UpdationOfVariables){ }`

Secondly,you need to declare or define variables `counter` and `array[]` in both methods `removeAllDuplicates()` and `del()` separately,**IF THEY ARE NOT CLASS ATTRIBUTES**!

Correct code :-

```
 public void removeAllDuplicates() {
    for (int i = 0; i < counter - 1;i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < counter;j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                del(j);
            }
        }
    }
 }

 public void del(int place) {
    for (int i = place; i < counter - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    array[counter] = 0;
    counter--;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to leanr an algorithm, then this kind of solution works.

But here, `Set` is a basic idea for your question. `Set` does not have duplicates. So what you have to do it to convert the array into a Set. You can do it by implementing a `Set data structure`. I will give a library code for the sake of completion.

So, I suggest you to stick to basic data-structures which can create more elegant solutions. :)

It seems harsh to get down votes in the very beginning in SO. But do not give up keep learning.

You can create your data structure for this.

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(someArray));
```